# Can I stop later parts of a pipeline from running if an earlier part failed?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I have a piped command such as:

```
set -euxo pipefail

echo 'hello' | foo | touch example.sh
```

This is the output:

```
$ set -euxo pipefail
$ echo hello
$ foo
$ touch example.sh
pipefail.sh: line 4: foo: command not found
```

I thought `set -e` would cause the script to exit however. But even though `foo` is unrecognized, the script is still executing the `touch` command. How do I get it to exit if `foo` fails?

Comment: All components of a pipeline happen at the same time. Your code stops any extra line **after** the pipe from executing. It can't stop other pipeline stages from being run.

Comment: So there's no way to exit when one fails?

Comment: Think about what a pipeline does: `echo hello | foo | touch example.sh` connects the stdout of a subshell which will run `echo` to the stdin of a subshell which will use `exec` to replace itself with `foo`, and the stdout of `foo` to the stdin of a subshell which will replace itself with `touch`. Then, **after** making those connections, it starts all three programs and runs them in parallel. Obviously, you can't tell if a program will fail before you even started it.

Comment: now, if you had `echo hello | foo | cat; touch example.sh`, **that** would behave the way you expect. (The `cat` is just a placeholder to show that the `foo` doesn't need to be in tail position).

Comment: OK. what if the command were this: gunzip file1 | gzip file1? The result of the first pipe is passed to the second pipe. These two aren't happening in parallel right? This is my real use case. We may have a regular .txt file coming and the program isn't exiting.

Comment: The commands don't matter. gunzip, gzip, cat, echo, it's all the same. "All components of a pipeline happen at the same time."

Comment: `gunzip -c <file1 | gzip >file2` is a better example of a pipeline, inasmuch as the processes are actually communicating over the FIFO. And yes, they happen at the same time. The `gzip` just has to sit and wait for content to be written by `gunzip` before it has anything to operate on, but it'll be unblocked as soon as there's enough data to fill its buffer -- so if you're recompressing a 10gb file and gzip needs maybe 32kb, it'll start operating as soon as gunzip finishes that much data, instead of waiting for the whole file to finish.

Comment: ...and in the `gunzip | gzip` case, `gzip` doesn't wait even for 32kb of output before it's started -- it gets invoked at the same time `gunzip` does; it just doesn't have anything to do (starts up but then sits around waiting for a blocking `read()` call to complete) until there's enough data ready for it to be useful.

Comment: On a different note, by the way, I strongly suggest reviewing the [exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) before using `set -e`, which has a wide enough array of unintuitive behaviors as to make hand-written error handling much more reliable and consistent.

Comment: OK thanks for all the insight into this issue. Next issue since I can't exit, how do I capture the exit codes for each command? I tried using echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" but nothing is returning. On a side note, I put #!/bin/bash at the top and extension is .sh. Is that enough to make it a bash script?

Comment: How do you actually invoke it? If you run it with `sh scriptname`, that overrides the shebang and uses `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: In my example, I'm doing bash script.sh. In real life, a wrapper script is calling the script and autosys is running the job.

Comment: Just running `/path/to/yourscript`, no preceding `sh` or `bash` or whatnot, will honor the shebang. Similarly, I'd suggest not putting any extension on your executable scripts at all; a `.sh` extension implies that something can be run with `sh`, which isn't true for bash -- and means that if you rewrote your script in a completely different language in the future, you'd need to either rename it and change all callers to use the new name, or have it be named misleadingly.

Comment: For a comparison, look at how Python *libraries* have `.py` extensions, but Python *scripts* don't conventionally have any extension at all -- you run `2to3`, not `2to3.py`, just like you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, even though `ls` is compiled as an ELF binary.

Comment: @HuaCha : In addition to what has been said here: Your pipeline doesn't make sense anyway, because `touch` does not read from stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really think of a pipeline of having "earlier" or "later" parts, except insofar as data moves through them from one end to the other: **All parts of a pipeline run at the same time.**

Consequently, you can't prevent later parts from starting if an earlier part failed, *because the later part started at the same time the earlier part did*.

---

The above being said, there *are* mechanisms to allow a pipeline to shut down early in the event of a failure -- mechanisms which work the same way without needing to set any non-default shell flags at all:

- If you're using a tool designed to be used on the right-hand side of a pipeline (unlike `touch`), it will be reading from stdin -- and will thus see an early EOF should the components to the left of it fail.
- If you're using a tool designed to be used on the left-hand side of a pipeline, it will receive a `SIGPIPE` when it attempts to write if the thing to the right of it is no longer running.

Of course, these mechanisms don't work if you're piping from a program that doesn't write to stdout, or into a program that doesn't read from stdin -- but such programs don't make much sense to use in pipelines anyhow.

Comment: OK, here's the real use case: gunzip file.gz | awk '{gsub("'"$ctrl_m"'","")} | gzip > file.gz If I pass a .txt file in to this line, the first gunzip command will fail but the rest of the pipe will continue. In this case, is there a way to shut down the pipeline early?

Comment: You can't use the same filename as both source and destination, and if you don't either use `-c` or feed it input from stdin, `gunzip` will just create an output file directly itself, not write to a pipeline at all. `gunzip -c file1.gz | awk '...' | gzip >file2.gz` will work. You'll get your `file2.gz` created either way, but you can just delete it if the pipeline fails.

Comment: That is to say: `filename="file.gz"; set -o pipefail; if gunzip -c <"$filename" | awk '...' | gzip >"$filename.tmp.$$"; then mv -- "$filename.tmp.$$" "$filename"; else echo "ERROR: Failure in pipeline" >&2; exit 1; fi` -- if you need to operate in a directory other users can write to safely, use `mktemp` to create your temporary file instead, thus avoiding symlink attacks. Note that you can't rely on `set -e` for correct handling here, and we're intentionally preventing it from operating by putting the error into a "checked" location inside the `if`.