# How can I stop processing a file and continue with the next one in a pipe?

Tags: bash, for-loop, pipe, continue

I want to process all files in a directory in a for loop and I have a bunch of scripts, which send data to each other through pipes. When one of the scripts fails on a file I'd like to stop processing that file immediately and continue with the next file. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  script1 < $file |\
  script2 |\
  ( script2_failed && continue || cat ) |\
  script3 > $file.out
done
```

Can something like it be done?

Comment: This may help <https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957985/8133920>.

Comment: sh/ksh/bash really aren't ideal for nonlinear control flow - they can do it, but it's not what they're best at.  I'd suggest moving to Python or C or something.

Comment: I believe this is how Bash works by default - can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Quasímodo and @l0b0 are right, I am making things too difficult. The standard behaviour of pipe and bash is what I need and I don't have to care. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You could trap the `ERR` signal and `continue` to the next iteration. For example:

```sh
trap continue ERR
for cmd in date xyz date; do
    $cmd 2>/dev/null
    echo test
done
```

output:

```
Tue 17 Mar 2020 03:23:24 PM MDT
test
Tue 17 Mar 2020 03:23:24 PM MDT
test
```

`xyz` fails with error `command not found` and triggers `continue` which starts the next iteration. For details about `continue` and `trap` builtin commands see: `help continue` and `help trap`.

Comment: Not familiar with `trap`, but won't it trigger `continue` after any error is received (after `trap` statement)? It looks quite unspecific.

Comment: yes, the error trap is triggered after a command with non-zero status.

Comment: It turned out that in fact I don't need to care for this situation - bash and pipe work as I need by standard. But thank you for showing me the trap command. I haven't known it.